# How to extract the values for a string?

Tags: shell

I have this type of data :

```
--Line1 : val1=10; val2=20; val3=30
--Line2 : val1=11; val2=21; val3=31
--Line3 : val1=12; val2=22; val3=32
--Line4 : val1=13; val2=23; val3=33
--Line5 : val1=14; val2=24; val3=34
--Line6 : val1=15; val2=25; val3=35
--Line7 : val1=16; val2=26; val3=30
```

Now, i am trying to write a script to get any particular value (say val1 for Line4) on the basis of string "Line1", Line2, etc.

Any hint? Working in linux.

Comment: Trying is fine, but that also means it's premature to ask a question here until you have something to show for your efforts. The most important thing to explain is **what you've tried**.

Comment: You can use regex to extract the values !

Comment: I could find this one solution for (val1 of Line1) - 
grep "Line1" txt.txt | grep "val1" | cut -d';' -f 1 | cut -d= -f 2